# javascript validate checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, opencart

I have the following code

```
$('#bnp-agree').keyup(function(e){
  if(!$(this).is(':checked').val())
    e.preventDefault();
}).focusout(function(){
  if(!$(this).is(':checked').val()){
    $('#bnp-agree-wrong').slideUp();
  } else {
    $('#bnp-agree-wrong').slideDown();
  }
});
```

i have the following div

```
<div class="text-danger" id="bnp-agree-wrong" style="display: none;">Трябва да се съгласите с общите условия на БНП Париба!</div>
```

I want just to validate that the user is checked this ckeckbox

```
<label><input type="checkbox" name="bnp-agree"><span>Прочетох и се съгласих</span></label>
```

How can i achieve it?

Comment: `is(':checked')` returns true/false.  You don't need `val()` there.  Also that could be simplified to just `this.checked` which is also a boolean true/false

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901712/how-to-check-whether-a-checkbox-is-checked-in-jquery

Isn't that exactly what you're looking for?

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is simple :) THERE IS NO id="bnp-agree" ATTRIBUTE IN THE CHECKBOX

Also thats an alternative;

```js
$('#bnp-agree').on("change",
function(){
  if($(this).prop("checked")){
    $('#bnp-agree-wrong').slideUp();
  } else {
    $('#bnp-agree-wrong').slideDown();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="text-danger" id="bnp-agree-wrong" style="display: none;">Трябва да се съгласите с общите условия на БНП Париба!</div>

<label><input type="checkbox" name="bnp-agree" id="bnp-agree"><span>Прочетох и се съгласих</span></label>
```